# xml.value() method in SQL Server (Getting a value inside an XML query)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, xquery

I have an XML Query like this:

```
<ChangeSet xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

   <Change DateTime="2011-12-02T09:01:58.3615661-08:00" UserId="3123">
      <Table ChangeType="Insert" Name="EVNT_LN_AFF">
         <Keys>
            <Key FieldName="DIR_CD" Value="NB" />
            <Key FieldName="LN_ID" Value="A" />
            <Key FieldName="EVNT_ID" Value="10T000289" />
         </Keys>
         <ChangedFields>
            <Field FieldName="DIR_CD" Previous="" Current="NB" />
            <Field FieldName="LN_ID" Previous="" Current="A" />
            <Field FieldName="EVNT_ID" Previous="" Current="10T000289" />
            <Field FieldName="UD_DTTM" Previous="" Current="12/2/2011 9:01:59 AM" />
            <Field FieldName="UD_USER_ID" Previous="" Current="3123" />
         </ChangedFields>
      </Table>
```

(The query goes on)

Now I want to use a statement like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [CHG_LOG_ID]
   , [EVNT_ID]
   , [DATA_XML_TXT]
   , [UD_DTTM]
FROM [MY_PROJ].[dbo].[EVNT_CHG_LOG]
WHERE DATA_XML_TXT.value('(/ChangeSet/Change/Table/ChangedFields/UD_USER_ID)[0]','varchar(50)') like '%3123%'
```

But when I execute the query, I don't get any results.

Comment: From your sample XML it appears you can have multiple `Change` elements in the `ChangeSet` element. Or even multiple Table elements. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested the following XQuery, and it should give you what you need:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [CHG_LOG_ID]
   , [EVNT_ID]
   , [DATA_XML_TXT]
   , [UD_DTTM]
FROM [MY_PROJ].[dbo].[EVNT_CHG_LOG]
WHERE DATA_XML_TXT.value('(/ChangeSet/Change/Table/ChangedFields/Field[@FieldName="UD_USER_ID"]/@Current)[1]','varchar(50)') like '%3123%'
```

**Note:** Indexing for XQuery starts at 1 instead of 0

Comment: That worked. I was not sure how to use "@Current" in my code. Thanks!